# The property of $A$ that satisfies $A^2={}^t\!A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ **real** matrix s.t.
\begin{align}
& A^2={}^t\!A \\
& A\neq I=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\\
& \mathrm{Inverse  \ matrix  \ of \ } A \mathrm{\  exists.}
\end{align}

And define the inner product $〈x,y〉$ as $$〈x,y〉=\sum_{k=1}^3 x_k \ \overline{y_k}$$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{C^3}.$

Then, prove that at least one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is a real number. $\cdots (\ast)$

At the pre-step of this problem, I had to prove that

・$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$
$\Rightarrow$ $\lambda^2=\overline{\lambda}$

・Eigenvectors that have different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Thus, I think these can be used to prove $(\ast)$.

Let $a, b, c\in \mathbb C$ be a eigenvalues of $A$.
It's sufficient to show that $a=\overline{a} , b=\overline{b}$ or $c=\overline{c}$.

From this, I have no idea what I have to do to prove $(\ast)$.

I'd like you to give me any idea.

Comment: *Hint*: any $(2n+1)\times(2n+1)$ real matrix has a real eigenvalue.

Comment: I see. Thank you. @user10354138